# How to apply x-bar structure to split verb phrases?

Tags: x-bar-theory

Consider the sentence "Who will John meet in the classroom?". What would the (s-structured) x-bar tree of this sentence look like? Does "will" still simply go in the T node, or is it a CP-specifier, or what? I'm having trouble charting it since "will" and "meet" are separated by "John".

I'm new to the site, so I'm not sure how plausible this is, but I'd appreciate a depicted tree if possible.

On an unrelated note, in a sentence such as "Which picture of himself will John hate?", what is considered the reflexive noun phrase (as it pertains to Condition A of traditional Binding Theory)? I know it'd normally be "himself", but is it "John" in this case, since "himself" precedes it?

Thanks.

Comment: "will" sits in C head position in this example

Answer (score -3):

Kiyoshigaang points to the direct answer to the question. On a GB-style analysis (Government and Binding), *who* is in spec of CP and *will* is in C of CP; both move to those positions from lower in the tree.

But the question references T of TP. Thus the question seems to be located in the generative tradition after about 1995, since the generative tradition did not start acknowledging TP until about that time. Producing an analysis that can be agreed upon becomes more difficult in this regard, since as the generative tradition has progressed, more and more functional categories have been added, e.g. AgrP, FocP, TopP, etc. A "correct" analysis and direct answer to the question is therefore increasingly debatable.

This site is inundated by this type of parse tree question. In my view, the questions bear witness to a major problem with the state of mainstream Chomskyan syntax and modern syntax courses in linguistics in general. Students are being required to produce parses of sentences using an increasingly complex system; they are therefore understandably frustrated and thus seeking help where they might find it. But due to the complexity of the system, it is often difficult to produce coherent answers to the questions. The experts often disagree.

This is of course not the answer that the question is seeking. Producing a clear answer would, though, be difficult, and drawing a modern X-bar-style tree that acknowledges TP is laborious. Perhaps this answer will, however, help generate skepticism about the value of producing such parses to begin with, in a system of syntax that is (in my view) overly complex.

Comment: The second paragraph is factually wrong: TP was introduced in *Syntactic Structures* in 1957 and it plays a crucial theoretical and empirical role in the works of Klima, Emonds and Jackendoff from the 1960s and early 1970s.

Comment: @Olivier, if you would, please cite a page number where TP appears in a syntax tree from one of the works you mention. If I can, I will check the source. If I'm wrong, I will acknowledge my mistake and correct my answer.

Comment: @Olivier, you've raised a serious accusation. I've asked for help verifying that the accussation is correct and my answer "factually wrong", and what I receive is silence. I'm going to poke around the library this afternoon. I'll take a look at Chomsky 1957. I'm pretty sure I will find no syntax trees showing TP in that book. I'll be back!

Comment: You should do your own homework, but for the benefit of anyone interested section (5.3) of Syntactic Structures (which is not really an obscure reference) explicitly points out the need of a rewriting rule involving Aux and though no tree appear there, this is only because Chomsky points out that the complete set of rewriting rules carries more information than a tree and points out explicitly how to construct the latter from the former. As for the others, you can have a look for instance at Klima and Bellugi (1966) page 190.

Comment: Then Jackendoff (1972), Emonds (1976), Emonds (1978), Roberts (1985), Baker (1988) and Pollock (1989), which, *taking for granted* that there is a T node above V popularized the hypothesis that there are two nodes above V: v and T. *That* hypothesis (the three-layered V) was only generally accepted in generative syntax in 1995, and I suspect you might be conflating it with the existence of T, which has been discussed since the very inception of the generative syntax.

Comment: @Olivier, I have checked the first two sources you listed, Chomsky (1957: sec. 5.3) and Klima and Bellugi (1966). The first source does not produce a single tree in that section, and "T", "TP", or "tense phrase" appear nowhere. The entire second source produces no tree at all, and "TP" or "tense phrase" also appear nowhere, but "T" does appear (although it is not entirely clear to me what it stands for; nowhere do they state that it is an abbreviation for "tense".

Comment: @Olivier, you are confused. Chomsky (1957: sec. 5.3) discusses the status of auxiliary verbs with respect to rewrite rules. He produces the following rule (p. 39): Verb --> aux + V. That rule results in an analysis of constituent structure that acknowledges the constituent in brackets in the following example as a consituent: "Fred [has done] the work".  The modern understanding of TP assumes the following constituent structure" "Fred [has done the work]". Thus there is no sense in which there is a TP in the modern sense in Chomsky (1957). You are quite confused.

Comment: @Olivier, the same situation is true of Klima and Bellugi (1966). They are applying transformations to strings, whereby the strings and transformations that they produce do not acknowledge constituent structure at all. Hence there is no TP present in the modern sense in their article, not in any sense.

Comment: @Olivier, I was, however, a bit inaccurate in what I wrote, insofar I stated that TP started appearing around 1995. TP started appearing in textbooks in the early nineties, e.g. Cowper (1991). It is associated most with Pollock (1989), who split IP into AgrP and TP, as you suggest in your last hedging message. Before 1989, there is therefore no sense in which TP occurred in trees. It is, for instance, not present in Radford's textbook (1988).

Comment: @Olivier, the long and the short of all this is that what I wrote in my original answer is mostly accurate. I would appreciate an apology.

Comment: *The modern understanding of TP assumes the following constituent structure" "Fred [has done the work]". Thus there is no sense in which there is a TP in the modern sense in Chomsky (1957).* Yes, you are stating the tautology that the modern account of TP is modern, though of course it is nowhere near as recent as you seem to think: the oldest publication I could track in five minutes of looking at the literature with the property you want is from 1972 (and quite famous, as it should be) and the constituent fact you consider crucial entered the mainstream of generative syntax at most in 1979.

Comment: Do your homework if you want to know more or at least have the courtesy to ask a question: you are well entitled to ignore branches of syntax you don't find interesting, but a statement like *[b]efore 1989, there is [...] no sense in which TP occurred in trees* is  plain embarrassing on a site supposedly dedicated to linguistics.

Comment: @Olivier, we cannot go over this further here. My email is tjo3ya@yahoo.com. Write to me if you dare, or provide your email, so I can initiate.